# How to get the usernames and hashed passwords of my Mongo atlas db users

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, flask-login, mongodb-atlas

For my flask application, I am trying to implement login and page access with flask-login. However, the examples of flask-login used online are all done using SQL and SQLAlchemy. I am going to use MongoDB Atlas to store my users. For the login function, I will need to compare the username and password of the person trying to log into my application with the username and password of the Mongo Atlas Db user. How can I get the usernames and passwords of the Mongo Atlas users with python?

Comment: Are you talking about users that you created with Python, or users that were added via the Atlas UI?

Comment: @Joe I am talking about the users that were added via the Atlas UI. But I want to access their usernames and hashed passwords using python for my flask-login

Comment: Pretty sure those aren't available via Python except maybe in the Atlas API.  You could validate the username/password using the `authenticate` function, or try to connect using the passed credentials.

Comment: @Joe what `authenticate` function does python have?

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/database.py#L1399